# defaced admin panel Extending the User model with custom fields in Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin

I added some fields to django user so I can define permission levels to users . by choosing each level in admin panel , you can access certain part of website .
but when i go to user panel in admin template , it work fine but defaced   .
here is my codes :
**models.py:**

```
class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    is_level_one = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_level_two = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_level_three = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

**admin.py**(simple version)

```
admin.site.register(CustomUser)
```

and this is the defaced view of admin user here :

[first image of /admin/basic_app/user](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1lsPK.png)
[second image of /admin/basic_app/user](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7rXpC.png)

***you see these are the problems :***
1.user permission box is gone and you can not assign permissions to users
2.last login and date join are separated
3.group box is almost gone
4.password field is filled with hashed password

***but** the 3 access levels i defined are still there ( you can see the in the bottom of the page as check boxes and actually works fine ) *

and here is my decoration codes if someone needs to use the :

```
def level_one_required(function=None, redirect_field_name=REDIRECT_FIELD_NAME, refused='basic_app:index'):
    actual_decorator = user_passes_test(
        lambda u: u.is_active and u.is_level_one,
        login_url=refused,
        redirect_field_name=redirect_field_name
)
    if function:
        return actual_decorator(function)
    return actual_decorator
```